# How to get specific value in MS Access using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to get the specific value in my Ms Access Database..
Example.
Here is my table in Ms Database..

I have 3 Columns, that is Name,Age and Telelphone number.
Here are the values ..

Row 1 = [Name = John ,Age =13,Telephone Num = 456)].

Row 2 = [Name = Mark, Age =11,telephone num = 123)].

Row 3 = [Name = Maye, Age =15,telephone num = 789)]

then Example I only want to get the Age of Mark and that is 11 
or John's telephone number and that is 456..and 
display it using textbox. 
All I want is to get specific value and I don't care about the other value..

Well im Using Visual Studio 2012 and MS Access 2010..

heres my code..
Im new about VB.net so that im not relly familiar about the codes..^_^

con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Vincelouie\Desktop\FBES INFO SYSTEM\Database1.accdb")
        con.Open()

```
    Dim selectString As String = "SELECT  Age FROM Table1"
    ' this line passes in the SQL statement and the OleDbConnection object.
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(selectString, con)

    'Send the CommandText to the connection, and then build an OleDbDataReader.

    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    reader.Read()
    StudentTextBox.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString()


    'Close the reader and the related connection.
    reader.Close()
    con.Close()
```

Thank you..
All help are really appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to teach you all about ADO.NET here.  If you want to learn the basics of data access in VB.NET then there are plenty of places that you can learn that.  Here are some code examples:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases

Addressing this question specifically, you will create an OleDbCommand containing an appropriate SQL query and call ExecuteScalar.  That thread I linked to provides an example.